# ERROR: Can't initialize batch_readline - may be the input source is a directory or a block device

Tags: mamp-pro

I have Mamp Pro. Im trying to import a databse via the command line as its too large for PHPMyAdmin using these instructions: http://nickhardeman.com/308/export-import-large-database-using-mamp-with-terminal/

When I enter the following im prompted for my password:

```
/applications/MAMP/library/bin/mysql -u root -p DBNAME.sql < /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/FOLDERNAME
```

However when I enter it I get this message:

```
ERROR: Can't initialize batch_readline - may be the input source is a directory or a block device.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you have something wrong with that command, it should be:

```
/applications/MAMP/library/bin/mysql -u root -p DBNAME < /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/FOLDERNAME/BACKUP_FILENAME.sql
```