# mysql restore in ubuntu 20.04

Tags: mysql, database, restore, ubuntu-20.04

i am using mysql5.7 in ubuntu 20.04, i have to restore sqldump using below command but it gives error

```
mysql -u root -p dev1database < /home/dubansal/dev1database.sql
```

ERROR: Can't initialize batch_readline - may be the input source is a directory or a block device.

Comment: possible duplicate : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28452021/error-cant-initialize-batch-readline-may-be-the-input-source-is-a-directory/29237277

Comment: Are you using the 32-bit version of MySQL 5.7? If so, the source `.sql` file cannot be larger than 4GB ...